# Firewall rule through group policy not detected

Tags: windows, powershell, firewall

I created a firewall rule to block inbound port 138 using the local group policy editor (image 1 and image 2). When I run the  **Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName ""** powershell command, I am not able to get the rule details though (Image 3). But when I try to query a rule that I did created using the windows firewall console, it works properly.
[image: port 138 through local group policy]
[image: port 138 rule details]
[image: powershell command]

Is there any reason why the rule created through the Group policy was not detected whereas the one created through the windows firewall settings console was being detected?

Comment: Are you able to see it when you run `Get-NetFirewallRule | Select-Object DisplayName`?

Comment: @robdynot visible then also. But the rule is visible in the "Windows Firewall with Advanced Settings" UI. When i try to query using cmd or powershell, it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName ""
```

do

```
Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName 138_block
```

Comment: I did do that. I just added the quotes as a placeholder for the name in this question.